# Apk is not being uploaded when the emulator runs for the first time

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Emulator was working fine but suddenly it has come up with this :

`emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
emulator: device fd:1280
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android SDK Tools" checkbox
 - Click "OK"`

The apk is being uploaded only when the emulator is online and not when its first launched . I tried the above steps but the Android SDK Tools are up to date .And nothing happens when i click "OK". How and What can resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also problems with this and I could never fix this. Maybe there is a timeout for waiting ob the emulator start up. So if the startup task too long, android studio cancels the deploying.

Alternatively try Geny-Motion (https://www.genymotion.com/). In my opinion it is much faster and easier to handle. Also the setup and integration is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem. This isn't a fix, but I've taken to simply starting the emulator manually. Then, when running my project, the APK is correctly copied.